# NullPointerException on Toast

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, toast

this is my code:

```
 case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_ERROR: {

                        mRadioProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayStopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mPlayStopButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Streaming not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;
                    }
```

and this is Crashlytics stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.INotificationManager.enqueueToast(java.lang.String, android.app.ITransientNotification, int)' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.Toast.show(Toast.java:286)
```

Code is in MainActivity, which includes a radio player.Is it because the user has already closed MainActivity, making the context invalid? How can I prevent the crash?

Comment: Try getApplicationContext instance of MaintActivity.this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Streaming not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Streaming not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible when expecting for callback or receive a broadcast after Activity is destroyed .To handle it check for activities existence first by `isFinishing()` method of `Activity` class.

```
if(!isFinishing()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Streaming not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the activity is alive and show toast as follows

```
if(!MainActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Streaming not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```